# clang optimisation flags for matrix vector calculations

Tags: clang, glm-math

I looked at disassembled code generated by clang from glm (a matrix vector library for 3d calculations) operations.

I noticed clang doing some 'vectorization' for double precision operations, eg. coercing two multiplications in one SIMD instruction.

However, for single precision calculations, the code seems vary bad to me. The instructions used are from the SSE instruction sets, and the registers MMX ones, but every mulitplication is done for one single float at a time, and even groups of assignments (eg. matrix assignment) are carried out by a large bunch of movss statements. Those bad assignments even hold for double precision code.

Why is that, are there any command line arguments that would motivate clang doing better? I know compilers do no magic, but a linear list of 16 memory-adjacent assignments should be optimizable in many ways I guess?

Answer (score 0):

In your assembly read xmm register is not a proof of vectorization, as the every double operation are now performed in SIMD register (even single).

Vectorization is not trivial for compiler, clang furnishes option like

```
clang -fslp-vectorize-aggressive file.c
```

it may help, else you may look for alternative, it exists a lot of library for matrix multiplication, MKL, boost-numeric, plasma, etc ... In my souvenirs GLM is old, good alternative exists.

Comment: You're right, xmm registers are used for single operations. On the other hand, with double precision operations, actually two channel operations are used. So I guessed I would see four channel operations for single precision, but no, its even worse.

Comment: I had a quick look on GLM (http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/index.html) if it is this library, by experience SIMD computation works only well on large buffer, not when you are manipulating a small piece of data (if you have a list of vertex you will never save something with SIMD). Moreover did you try to use mem align allocator (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/increasing-memory-throughput-with-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4-streaming-load)

Comment: I do not have collections (eg. lists) of vertex data, but some few matrices or some vertices on stack. However, every single vector by matrix product should have a good gain by SIMD, as it already consist of 64 float multiplications and a bunch of additions. If four of them could be done in a single step, one may expect a 4x gain. As there are no collections but many operations on stack, caches should be hot and should not throttle the work.

Comment: GLM also has some native SIMD implementations, but those rely on special datatypes that need to be converted from the normal ones, and only some operations are possible. So forth and back conversions would eat up all benefits.

Comment: And you gave hint to memory alignment, maybe the compiler need manual hints to align short lived stack based structures for SIMD?